# PLSQL Insert in For Loop

Tags: oracle, plsql

I got an PL/SQL script to insert data from another table, but the result was not as i expected. The insert in BBB table only save the first row of d_rec loops. When i tried to print/output of d-Rec in another sql, it give me all the rows that saved in yyy table.

i already tried using cursor, but the result still the same.

```
DECLARE
GROUP_SEQ NUMBER;
TRANS_SEQ NUMBER;
ID NUMBER;
PP NUMBER := 1;
TRANS_ID NUMBER;
TRANS_SUM NUMBER;
UNIT VARCHAR(6);
DEBET NUMBER;
CREDIT NUMBER;

BEGIN
FOR v_rec in (SELECT unit from xxx)
LOOP
   FOR d_rec in (SELECT ID, TRANS_SUM, UNIT from yyy where unit = v_rec.unit )
   LOOP

     UPDATE YYY_SEQUENCE 
       SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + 1
       WHERE SEQ_NAME = 'GROUP_SEQ'
       RETURNING SEQ_COUNT 
       INTO GROUP_SEQ;
       COMMIT;

      INSERT INTO AAA (ID, SEQ) VALUES (ID, GROUP_SEQ);
      WHILE PP <= 4
      LOOP
         UPDATE YYY_SEQUENCE 
         SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + 1
         WHERE SEQ_NAME = 'TRANS_SEQ'
         RETURNING SEQ_COUNT 
         INTO TRANS_SEQ;
         COMMIT;

         IF (PP < 3) THEN
             DEBET := TRANS_SUM;
             CREDIT := 0;
         ELSE             
             DEBET := 0;
             CREDIT := TRANS_SUM;
         END IF;
         PP := PP +1;
         INSERT INTO BBB(ID, SEQ, UNIT, DEBET, CREDIT) VALUES (ID, TRANS_SEQ, UNIT, DEBET, CREDIT);
         COMMIT;
      END LOOP;
   END LOOP;
PP :=1;
END LOOP;
END
```

The First insert give me all the rows in d_rec data. But the second insert only give me the first row of d_rec data.

Comment: Wouldn't the innermost loop spin forever, as `PP` is never incremented? Although as `KAS` isn't defined this can't be the code you're actually running anyway... You may also want to reset `PP` back to one before that innermost loop, rather than after the `d_rec` loop - that might be why you only get a single insert, assuming there is only one unit from the outermost loop; but it isn't clear.

Comment: sorry, the code is only a snippet of the actual code. so there might be some errors. I have edited to adjust the code. hopefully it will be easier to understand.

Comment: sorry, you are right. PP positioning that make only first row inserted... thx..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are resetting the `PP` counter after the `d_rec` loop, inside the `v_rec` loop; which means that once it's been incremented to 4 for the first `d_rec` for a unit, subsequent `d_rec` iterations skip over the innermost loop - because `PP <= 4` is never true for those.

A quick fix would be to move that reset in a loop:

```
...
      END LOOP;
      -- reset PP after this loop
      PP :=1;
   END LOOP;
   -- instead of after this loop
   --PP :=1;
END LOOP;
END
```

But it would probably be clear if you reset immediately before using it:

```
...
      INSERT INTO AAA (ID, SEQ) VALUES (ID, GROUP_SEQ);
      -- reset here
      PP := 1;
      WHILE PP <= 4
      LOOP
         PP := PP +1;

         ...

         IF (PP < 3) THEN
             DEBET := TRANS_SUM;
             CREDIT := 0;
         ELSE             
             DEBET := 0;
             CREDIT := TRANS_SUM;
         END IF;

         INSERT INTO BBB(ID, SEQ, UNIT, DEBET, CREDIT) VALUES (ID, TRANS_SEQ, UNIT, DEBET, CREDIT);
         COMMIT;
      END LOOP;
   END LOOP;
END LOOP;
END
```

Or get rid of the explicit variable altogether - so it doesn't need to be declared, reset or incremented - and use [a for loop](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/FOR-LOOP-statement.html) instead:

```
...
      INSERT INTO AAA (ID, SEQ) VALUES (ID, GROUP_SEQ);
      FOR PP IN 1..4
      LOOP
         ...

         IF (PP < 3) THEN
             DEBET := TRANS_SUM;
             CREDIT := 0;
         ELSE             
             DEBET := 0;
             CREDIT := TRANS_SUM;
         END IF;

         INSERT INTO BBB(ID, SEQ, UNIT, DEBET, CREDIT) VALUES (ID, TRANS_SEQ, UNIT, DEBET, CREDIT);
         COMMIT;
      END LOOP;
   END LOOP;
END LOOP;
END
```

Incidentally, all those commits look wrong - they make it impossible to restart on failure but also have a detrimental effect on performance. And you could probably simplify this to fewer loops.